# How can I convert any file to pdf in C#

Tags: pdf, c#, asp.net

can anyone suggest to me the best opensource library in asp.net core that converts any file format into the .pdf format? there is a library with the name groupdocs which is converting most of the documents but it is not open source. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "any file"? What formats are you looking for as your input?

Comment: I guess Hassan wants to convert office files, images, text files, HTML files. Hassan, please edit your question to add all file types you think will be necessary, otherwise your question is too vague. Thanks! :-) I know that the open source Alfresco converts dozens of file types to PDF (as part of its preview feature), but it is not C#. I hope something similar is available for C#.